# mongodb error connection closed in flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter

my application works fine before but now when I Write to mongodb it give me this error

## [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MongoDB ConnectionException: connection closed: The socket connection has been reset by peer.

Possible causes:

- Trying to connect to an ssl/tls encrypted database without specifiyng
  either the query parm tls=true or the secure=true parameter in db.open()
- The server requires a key certificate from the client, but no certificate has been sent
- Others

I don't know what is the cause of this error.

ps: it connect to mongodb, and I can read the data but, I can't write the data

I try to use deferent user access but it doesn't work,
I check user privileges and it's all right

Answer (score 0):

The error is because I use save() method which  is now deprecated.
To fix:
I use update(), updateOne, updateMany and it fix the Issue.